# Why is zsh substituting this string?

Tags: zsh

I type

```
git remote add dokku dokku@$DOKKU_HOST:hello
```

zsh turns the remote URL into

```
dokku@.ello
```

I've tried searching the web, but I don't exactly know what I'm searching for since I'm unfamiliar with the behavior/feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently zsh is trying to interpret the trailing :h as some sort of substitution modifier. Try using braces:

```
git remote add dokku dokku@${DOKKU_HOST}:hello
```

And make sure DOKKU_HOST has a value.

Comment: `:h` Removes the trailing pathname component, leaving just the head, `.ello`

Comment: That was it. Thanks! Zsh uses csh style modifiers from here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Shell_Scripting/Modifiers